# CDATA to ignore & in XSD

Tags: xsd, cdata

I need the xml parser/validator to ignore the presense of &

How do I accomplish it by using CDATA in xsd.

This is snippet of xsd:

```
 <xs:simpleType name="values">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
     <xs:enumeration value="IN & OUT"/>
     <xs:enumeration value="XYZ"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

I tried using CDATA as follows but in vain as I get xsd validation error:

```
 <xs:simpleType name="values">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
     <xs:enumeration value="IN <![CDATA[&]]> OUT"/>
     <xs:enumeration value="XYZ"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thansk in advance.

Comment: Using structural content in attribute values is not possible. Beyond elements, this also means that you can't have a CDATA section in an attribute value.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use the entity reference `&amp;` instead of the character `&`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using an entity reference:

```
  <xs:simpleType name="values">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="IN &amp; OUT"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="XYZ"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

or a decimal reference:

```
  <xs:simpleType name="values">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="IN &#38; OUT"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="XYZ"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. I find it interesting how that line in the second snippet is actually black instead of the properly coloured elements.

May I ask what the validation error is? It may help in pinpointing what is exactly wrong with that line of code. It may be true that the parser will ignore the & sign, but have you tried replacing the & with '&' ? The thing is, I have a feeling you're setting the enumeration value to

```
    "IN <![CDATA[&]]> OUT"/>
```

Which would... obviously not pass the validation. Either that or the parser completely passes over that line and only takes in XYZ as an enum value.

1. What's the error.
2. Have you tried replacing & with

   ```
   &amp;
   ```

   Since it's an escape entity?

Cheers.

Comment: 1) The validation error in XMLSPY - charcter <is gramatically unexpected.

2)I do not want to use &amp as it expects our code change to convert it to 'AND' and we do not want to do that in our code.

Comment: @joerobles: Does your code only change `&amp;` entity references to "AND"? If so, you could use a decimal reference: `&#38;`

Comment: Ahh I understand. I'll see if I can come up with a solution without compromising your wants. Have you tried googling the error? =)

Comment: Google searched but no luck. Also most of the examples in web are for simple elements and also not in xsds.

Comment: @joerobles what are you using to parse the xsd schema? =) Just wondering. I'm thinking there may be some settings on the parser that allow you to customize what to parse and what not to parse.

Comment: XMLSPY tool parser and validatorboth fail. Not sure about javax.xml.validator. I get the feeling that CDATA is applicable to XML but not XSDs. Only &amp; or &#38 can be used in XSDs. Is this a valid statement? Thx

Comment: Yeah you typcically save the CDATA tags for xml, since you're comparing the xml to the xsd when validating it. Usually you'd be ignoring something in the xml rather than the schema. =P I talked to a few people at work just now and they agree with me on that. Also I believe yeah, right now &amp; or &#38 is your best option. I'll keep looking though. Cheers. =)